# Does nix upgrade support restarting and reconfiguring services?

Tags: nix

I'm new to nix. I see that there is `--upgrade` option that allows to install a new version package, but what if this is just a configuration change and the service just needs a signal to reload the configuration?

It could be notified on the filesystem event but will nix touch file belonging to a different version of a package?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Some services are restarted when their configuration changes, while others are not.

I don't know how it's implemented, but no, content in the Nix store is immutable so no file touching happens within the Nix store (`/nix/store`). However, on NixOS there are *some* files which are not in the Nix store; Some examples are in `/etc`. Such files are not subject to the immutability of the Nix store.

Answer (score 1):

If the service is configured using NixOS options then the systemd unit will usually refer to the configuration file directly. Changing the options will generate a new config file, cascading to cause the unit file to change. NixOS will interpret this as a signal to restart the service.

## `--upgrade` doesn't do what you probably think it does

That said, `nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade` doesn't change how the new configuration is applied. It's just an alias for `nix-channel --update && nixos-rebuild switch`.